# How to change my x axis while using pandas and matplotlib?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, matplotlib

I'm simply asking how I would go about changing my x axis. I've been having trouble finding an answer online that worked with my current setup.

This is my plotting code:

```
import scipy.io as spio
import numpy as np
import csv
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib as plt


onfile='file'

s=spio.readsav(onfile,python_dict=True,verbose=True)

a=np.asarray(s['a'])
b=np.asarray(s['b'])
c=np.asarray(s['c'])
d=np.asarray(s['d'])


df = pd.DataFrame({'a':a,'b':b,'c':c,'d':d})
df.plot(x='a',y=['b','c','d'],kind='line')
```

I'm trying to plot within the "x" axis of 50-60

Comment: First, `ax=df.plot... ` then `ax.set_xlim(50,60)`.

Comment: @ anishtain4, I appreciate the tough love. Helped me solve it the way I should have in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `axes.set_xlim`:

```
ax = df.plot(x='a',y=['b','c','d'],kind='line')
ax.set_xlim(50,60)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ended up looking at the matplotlib.pyplot documentation. solution ended up being:

```
x=a
y=b
plt.axis(xmin=50, xmax=60, ymin = -200, ymax = 200)
plt.scatter(x,y)
```

Thanks for all of the help!